# How should one synchronize customized kernel patches?

Tags: linux, kernel, patch

I maintain a customized kernel, also I provide patches that you can use directly for major version of kernel source code, now I got a classic problem,

I developed the patch based on `3.7.8` kernel, as newer version `3.7.9` is out, I had to develop the patch for `3.7.9` as well, but how should I do this quickly?

Right now, I download the whole source code of 3.7.9, migrate the code to new version of kernel manually, and generate the patch from newer kernel source. That looked stupid and inefficient.

```
-------------------          A    --------------------
| My 3.7.8 kernel |         --->  |  My 3.7.9 kernel |
-------------------                --------------------
      /|\                                 /|\
       | B                                 | C
       |                                   |
--------------------------   D    --------------------------
| Mainline 3.7.8 kernel  |  --->  |  Mainline 3.7.9 kernel |
--------------------------        --------------------------
```

What I want is procedure `A` directly, rather than doing `D` first, then `C`, do you think that's possible?

Comment: If your patch is non-intrusive you can try and merge 3.7.9 in your 3.7.8 kernel with rebase, fix possible conflicts and generate the patch again from there?

Answer (score 1):

Use the git version control system for what it was created. Grab a clone of the kernel, and add your patches to it on a local branch. Whenever you need to move to the next version, `git pull` that one and `git rebase` your patches on top. That will solve *most* of the adjusting to the next version, but the internal Linux API is *not* stable, so be prepared for random fallout.